# How many levels beyond level 1416 are there in Microsoft Minesweeper in mode Adventure?

Tags: minesweeper, microsoft

I am a big fan of this game. As you can see, my current level is 1416 (Spanish, sorry!) I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I would like to know what the highest level is.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many levels are there in Minesweeper adventure mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/how-many-levels-are-there-in-minesweeper-adventure-mode)

Comment: I've already referred to that one below :)

Comment: So both questions need some rephrasing, perhaps?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This question is about the Windows 10 version, while the [other one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/97856/4797) is about the Windows 8 version. Apparently, the two versions are different from each other. If I'm not mistaken, then this question isn't a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 4):

The number of *levels* seems to be infinite.

However, the Win8 edition had a [score limit of 2147483648 (2^31)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/how-many-levels-are-there-in-minesweeper-adventure-mode) after which the *score* would start counting back. Assuming a roughly linear progression of points over the levels, you'd end up at about 1000 levels with the 32 bit limit. You've clearly passed that, so under Win10 this is now probably a 64 bit integer.

That means that score limit would now be 2^63. Assuming progression speed is the same for the Win10 version, you'd therefore have to hit **level 4.2 trillion** (4.2*10^12) before hitting that particular limit. Note: there's probably nothing stopping you from continuing to play more *levels* after that, just the *score* decreases (and would probably go back up again after another 4.2 trillion levels). Good luck establishing those empirically though :)